# System.loadLibrary fails with Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memmove4"

Tags: java, android

```
System.loadLibrary("nativefaceswap");
```

When I run my app I found this type of error in Android Studio.
In logcat shows:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   "__aeabi_memmove4"

Comment: You need to compile your library for the lowest API that you want to support. In this case, you compile the library for API ≥ 21 and try to run it on lower API but the ABI for `memmove` was changed in API 21.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This is gradle experimental example.**

The Ndk is forward compatable.
You need to tell the ndk the minimum version of your app.
example: inside app gradle file:

```
ndk {
        moduleName = 'MyLib'
        toolchain = 'clang'
        cppFlags.addAll(['-fexceptions' ,'-frtti','-std=c++11','-Wall'])
        ldLibs.addAll(['android','log','atomic'])
        stl "c++_static"
        platformVersion = "21" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<- Minimum version
    }
```