# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol “__aeabi_memmove4”

Tags: android-ndk, android-library, android-build, dlib, ndk-build

When I run this example (https://github.com/alex011235/FaceSwap) I found this type of runtime error in Android Studio. I can select two images but when I click the button to swap the face, it crashed and the message show in logcat:

> com.tzutalin.dlibtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.tzutalin.dlibtest, PID: 31370
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memmove4" referenced by "/data/app/com.tzutalin.dlibtest-2/lib/arm/libnativefaceswap.so"...
>
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
>
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
>
> at com.alex.faceswap.FaceSwap.(FaceSwap.java:57)
>
> at com.alex.faceswap.ActivitySelfieSwap$1.run(ActivitySelfieSwap.java:168)
>
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

The row that make me get error is the following row (FaceSwap.java:57).

> System.loadLibrary("nativefaceswap");

I hope to get use of this example and I cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Did you look at the suggestions for this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346206/system-loadlibrary-fails-with-error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-fail

Comment: Sure. but I did it and nochange. Preshap I have done something wrong?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, and I have no time to try this project myself, but I do not think you are doing something wrong... Seems like the library loading fails due to some inconsistency, but I cannot tell for sure. Perhaps it is related to the Android version? What version did you try it on, and can you try on another one?